# Don't understand how to logout of FusionAuth from Django Application

Tags: python, django, fusionauth

I am writing a **Django** app that uses a 3rd-Party Authentication Service implemented with **FusionAuth**.

I can successfully register and login (using the authorization code flow).

However, logging out is not working.  I can logout from the local **Django** app, but when I try to login after that FusionAuth recognizes that my `access_token` is still valid and just goes directly to the redirect page (the page you usually goto after successfully logging into **FusionAuth**).

Clearly I don't understand something about **FusionAuth**.  I have tried both the [python client](https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-python-client/blob/a2061ea5ec04a8946711e9e209dc8f665405316f/src/main/python/fusionauth/fusionauth_client.py#L1524) and the [restful API](https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/login#logout-a-user) and I don't really understand what it does.  According to the documentation it "...is intended to be used to remove the refresh token and access token cookies if they exist on the client and revoke the refresh token".  Why then is the `access_token` still valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem like a couple of issues here.

First, you need to redirect the browser to https://your.fusionauth.instance/oauth2/logout and that will delete your FusionAuth SSO session. That will stop the behavior of FusionAuth redirecting you. This is because you have an SSO session cookie, and going to that URL will delete it.

Second, if you want to revoke the access token, that takes a bit more work. It is stateless. It's not the same as a session, and is distinct from the SSO session mentioned above. The access token is something you present to other APIs, not to FusionAuth. Here's some more info: https://fusionauth.io/learn/expert-advice/tokens/revoking-jwts

Hope this helps.